# How to change my storage from data/data to Android/data

Tags: android, database, local-storage, storage

am a rookie. The present location of my app folder when installed is in data/data but I want to change the folder location(com.time.notes) to Android/data which is where alot of the folder of the apps I install shows, this is the code am presently trying.

```
   public void backup(String item) {
    OutputStream myOutput = null;
    InputStream myInput = null;
    File directory;
    String databasePath = "/data/data/"+getPackageName()+"/databases/Memo.db";
    File f = new File(databasePath);

    if (f.exists()) {
        try {

            directory = new File("/mnt/sdcard/"+getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)+"/Backup");
            if (!directory.exists())
                directory.mkdir();
            if (item.equals("Backup")) {

                myOutput = new FileOutputStream(directory.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "/"+getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));

                myInput = new FileInputStream(databasePath);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Backup Location " + directory, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (item.equals("Restore")) {
                myInput = new FileInputStream(directory.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "/"+getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));

                myOutput = new FileOutputStream(databasePath);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Backup Restored Successfully ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            myOutput.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        } finally {
            try {
                if (myOutput != null) {
                    myOutput.close();
                    myOutput = null;
                }
                if (myInput != null) {
                    myInput.close();
                    myInput = null;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but have you tried changing `"/data/data/"` to the path you want?

Comment: And have you gone over [Saving files](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) from the documentation?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes I have but it didnt work. what I want to do is change the present location from /data/data/ to /Android/data location. what am I not doing right

Comment: @cricket_007 just to be sure. How am I suppose to change "/data/data/" to the path I want?

Comment: Look at the string in your code that literally says `"data/data"` have you tried to change that and what happens when you do?

Comment: @cricket_007 , tnk u 4 ur comment but what am I suppose to change it to, I don't want to assume it, am still a rookie

Comment: Well, you said exactly where you want to put the data... "Android/data", yes? Start with that. I don't know exactly what you want, but you should be willing to experiment with the code. The best way to learn is to try, in my opinion. If you get an error, try to read it and understand how what you did would break something

Comment: @cricket_007  the folder of my app is currently stored in this location data/data but I want it saved in this location Android/data, this where I see the folder of other apps installed. I also want to save my files in that location (the files stored here are named in a package name e.g com.xxxx.yyy)

Comment: Yes, I know that by reading the question. Have you changed that string in your code, or not? Also, I'm fairly sure that link I posted to the documentation does exactly what you want

Comment: @cricket_007, yes i have tried still no changes